# Move DevTest Lab VM to another DevTest Lab

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-devtest-labs

I'm trying to move a VM custom image from one DevTest Lab to another and can't seem to find an easy way to accomplish that. My VM is using managed disks and also has a data disk.

I've read the following article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-devtest-labs-changes-in-exporting-custom-image-vhd-files/ and it states that

> Azure DevTest Lab now generates a managed image and "*…This allows
>   Sysprep'ed/deprovisioned custom images to support data disks in
>   addition to the OS disk through a single image.*"

This is fine but the image that is created can't be exported.

Is it even possible to accomplish, am I missing something?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is fine but the image that is created can't be exported.

The article you posted is right, you can follow it to **export the VM OS disk(not image)** to your local machine. You should export the VM OS disk from the **Resource group which contains your Devtest VM**. The main steps are below:

1. Generate your VM
2. Go to Azure Portal > find the resource group which name contains your DevtestLab VM :
   [image]
3. Then, you can find the Disk and export it to your local machine:
   [image]
4. Go to your another Devtest Lab > Configuration and plocies > Custom images > Add > Enter your VHD location and choose the OS type > OK > the coustom image will be uploaded  Then you can use it to create your Devtest VM. 
   [image]

Comment: Thanks, this works fine for a VM that has only an OS Disk, will there be a way to export an image that has datadisks in one simple operation instead of exporting each disks separately?  Recreating the custom image in the other DevTest Lab requires multiple steps : 1) create image from VHD 2) create a VM from image 3) Attach datadisks to VM 4) create the new image that has the datadisk.

Comment: Hi @PatLac, About the Data disk in Dev test Lab: You cannot create the image with data disks.The custom image is for OS base. If you want to use the data disk in another Dev test Lab, I think you'd better copy the data from the data disk to the new data disk in another Dev Test Lab. So, there is no way to use a data disk in another Dev test Lab directly.

Comment: @PatLac . Additional, you can also upvote for this idea in [this User Voice Page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/320373-devtest-labs/suggestions/14842470-deploy-a-os-template-with-attached-data-discs),   Azure DevTest Labs Team has planned to started it.

Comment: @wayne-yang-msft , Thanks for the details, I will work on this.